# sharedpreference handling

Tags: android, storage, sharedpreferences

I have made a program code for shared preference in android. But i am confused with sharedpreference. I am updating the sharedpreference if its not the same as earlier but every time i get the same value when i retrieve its value. Also please let me knw how to delete sharedpreference on onDestroy().

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    resid=bundle.getString("locid");

    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String prefresid = app_preferences.getString("preflocid", null);
     Log.i("pref res id is",""+prefresid);
    if(prefresid!=null)
    {
        if(resid.equalsIgnoreCase(prefresid))
        {
                Log.i("preference res id is the same","");
        }
        else
        {

            SharedPreferences.Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit();
            Log.i("preference res id is not same","creating new");
            //SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("myfile", 0);
           //   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
             e.putString("preflocid",resid);
             e.commit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
          Log.i("new preference res id created",""+prefresid);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
          editor.putString("preflocid", resid);
          editor.commit();
          Log.i("new preference res id created","");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have just one object of default SharedPreference and have editor onto that like:

```
SharedPreferences s_pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor edit=s_pref.edit();
```

now you will have to use this editor directly wherever it is required.

Comment: Thanks for replying but all this has already been done.As u can c in the code. Anything wrong in code ?? plz tell me.

Comment: take single instance of object as i suggested for editor.you have taken two different objects.take it globally under the line where you declare your s_pref. and then just use editor to put values to s_pref.don't create objects at each place.

Comment: nice one. How could i do that. Anyways thanks for helping really appreciate it.Its working good now.:-)

Comment: how can i clear the sharedPreference? I mean i have done it in onDestroy() but i never call finish on that activity. Also next time i start the app it shows last value stored in it. my code is            public void onDestroy()
 {  
  super.onDestroy();
  SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  app_preferences.edit().remove("myfile");
  app_preferences.edit().clear(); 
  app_preferences.edit().commit();   
 }

Comment: should i declare editor globally and use its object everywhere? even in onDestroy()??

Comment: Actually I haven't cleared my s_pref ever in my apps,But looking at the answer of Eric Nordvik,you might be getting it to work.Where do you exactly want your s_pref to be cleared? I mean,you can put it on Pause() and re create in onResume() but i think,this is abnormal scenario.s_pref are to be used to store the value throughout the app.So if you distroy it,it is of no use using them in your app.

Comment: @samirsingh: yes..definately.you can use the same object anywhere in your class.

Comment: just have a look at this http://pastie.org/3478236  what i want to do is check whether a user has changed his restaurant selection and if he is selecting the restaurant first time that means he is visiting the app first time. then shared pref value should be null and new preference should be created which stores the resid value. And if he goes back and again selects the same restaurant then shared preference value should remain unchanged. SO this means as soon as app exits the sharedpreference should clear. Any idea??? If u can give me ur mail id i will mail u the complete flow. Thnx

Comment: But when he installs the application,your shared preference values would already be cleared.Once he selects a restaurant,new pref.will be written.Then you will just need to edit it as and when required.I don't see any reqiurement of clearing s_pref from this,As long i understand above comment.May be,i didn't get the thing properly.

Comment: i m not allowed to comment a lot in this thread so plz if u can give ur email id i can mail u complete details.

Comment: You can invite me to chat when you are able to chat in chatroom.I can surely help you there.

Comment: God. My Bad luck dont have much reputations. Anyways u did ur best to help me. Thanks

Comment: @samirsingh: glad to help :) invite me to chat for your problem anytime.i will help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8297/discussion-between-samir-singh-and-hiral)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in your code will only change the value of the preference once, namely the first time you read it. The first time it is null, which means you go into the else and save "locid" to "preflocid". The next time "locid" is set to and you will go into the if and then into the first if because "locid".equalsIgnoreCase(prefresid).

To remove preferences in onDestroy, just call this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  SharedPreferences.Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit();
  e.clear();
  e.commit();
}
```